# Error on Publishing ECL Items

Tags: publishing, templating, tom.net, ecl

To publish ECL Items we have placed a custom build TBB to add external binary to our file system.

On publishing ECL Items we're getting error as `Cannot access a closed Stream.`

Error:

> The number of render failures has exceeded its specified failure limit
>   of 0. Cannot access a closed Stream.
>
> Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing Errorcode: 854 User: NT
>   AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
>
> StackTrace Information Details:    at System.IO.Stream.CopyTo(Stream
>   destination)    at System.IO.Stream.CopyTo(Stream destination)    at
>   ECLItems.Templating.PublishingECLItems.Transform(Engine
>   engine, Package package)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.AssemblyMediator.Transform(Engine
>   engine, Template template, Package package)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.RunTemplate(Engine
>   engine, Package package, String templateUri, String className)    at
>   Tridion.Templating.CSharpTemplate.CSharpSourceTemplate.Transform(Engine
>   __engine, Package __package)    at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.Transform(Engine
>   engine, Template template, Package package)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template
>   template, Package package)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package
>   package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
>   at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine
>   engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template
>   template, Package package)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package
>   package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
>   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformPackage(Template
>   template, Package package)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformItem(Template
>   template, IdentifiableObject itemToRender)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.TemplatingRenderer.Render(ResolvedItem
>   resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget
>   target, RenderedItem renderedItem, RenderContext renderContext)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(ResolvedItem
>   resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget
>   target, RenderContext context)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.RenderAndPackage(ResolvedItem
>   resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget
>   target, List`1 processedItems, PublishTransaction publishTransaction,
>   TransportPackage transportPackage)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.RenderAndPackage(ResolvedItem
>   resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget
>   target, List`1 processedItems, PublishTransaction publishTransaction,
>   TransportPackage transportPackage)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.HandlePublishRequest(PublishTransaction
>   publishTransaction)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.ProcessPublishTransaction(PublishTransaction
>   publishTransaction)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Publisher.QueueMessageHandler.HandleMessage()

**TBB Logic :**

```
IContentResult contentResult = eclItem.GetContent(null);
if (contentResult != null)
 {
    using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
         contentResult.Stream.CopyTo(stream);
         _engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddBinary(stream, fileName, "ECL_Default", component, contentType);
    }
  }
```

**ECL Provider :** `GetContent` logic

```
  public IContentResult GetContent(IList<ITemplateAttribute> attributes)
        {
            string JsessionId = string.Empty;
            if (this.Info.url == null) return null;

            string url = Image.GetPhotoUrl(this.Info.url, out JsessionId);
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "JSESSIONID=" + JsessionId);
                using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(webClient.DownloadData(url)))
                {
                    return Provider.HostServices.CreateContentResult(stream, stream.Length, this.Info.MimeType);
                }
            }
        }
```

Though `GetContent` method successfully return `IcontentResult`,but however we're Unable to add `IcontentResult.Stream` to `AddBinary` method.

**Update**

When we use `IContentResult` stream directly in `AddBinary` method,getting similar error  Cannot access a closed Stream.

> Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing Errorcode: 854 User: NT
>   AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
>
> StackTrace Information Details:    at
>
> System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()    at
>
> System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Position(Int64 value)    at
>
> System.IO.Stream.set_Position(Int64 value)    at
>
> Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.Binary..ctor(Stream content, String filename, IdentifiableObject location, String
>    variantId, Component relatedComponent, String mimeType,RenderInstruction renderInstruction)    at
>
> Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderedItem.AddBinary(Stream
>   content, String filename, String variantId, Component
>   relatedComponent, String mimeType)

Answer (score 4):

The error you are getting is a .NET error in the `CopyTo()` method, that tries to copy a closed stream.
I'm wondering if it wouldn't be easier to use the `IContentResult` stream object directly inside your `AddBinary` call.

> `_engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddBinary(contentResult.Stream, fileName, "ECL_Default", component, contentType);`

UPDATE

As you get the same issue when using the stream directly, this is caused by your 
using statement here

```
 using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(webClient.DownloadData(url)))
 {
       return Provider.HostServices.CreateContentResult(stream, stream.Length, this.Info.MimeType);
 }
```

the 'using' will dispose the stream when you return the content result, so the stream is no longer accessible.

I think you can safely change this to

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(webClient.DownloadData(url);
return Provider.HostServices.CreateContentResult(stream, stream.Length, this.Info.MimeType);
```

Comment: When we use directly in `AddBinary `,  getting same error  as System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Position(Int64 value)
   at System.IO.Stream.set_Position(Int64 value)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.Binary..ctor(Stream content, String filename, IdentifiableObject location, String variantId, Component relatedComponent, String mimeType, RenderInstruction renderInstruction)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderedItem.AddBinary(Stream content, String filename, String variantId, Component relatedComponent, String mimeType)

Comment: see my update in the answer

Comment: +1 for not copying to memory stream. ECL will stream the data through from the external content system to the Tridion publishing engine without keeping large binaries fully in memory - so you can as well take advantage of that. Unless of course you have problems with your server being too fast and using too little memory. :)